# Find $\mu((0, 1])$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on the Borel sets of $(0,\infty)$ and that $\mu((x,2x])=\sqrt x,$ for any $x>0.$ Find $\mu((0,1]).$

$$\begin{split}\mu\left((0,1]\right)&=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac 1{2^n}, \frac 1{2^{n-1}}\right]\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\left(\left(\frac 1{2^n}, \frac 1{2^{n-1}}\right]\right)&&\text{bc the sets are disjoint and $\mu$ is a measure}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1{2^n}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\frac {1}{1-\frac 1{\sqrt 2}}\end{split}$$

I think it's impossible to have missed something in four steps, but you never know.

Comment: Your final answer seems to include a nonexistant $n=0$ term.

Comment: @Michael Oh thank you.

Comment: By generalizing and extending your argument, you can also show $$\mu(A) = \int_A \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{2}-1)}\,d\lambda$$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.  (in particular, showing $\mu$ exists)

Comment: thank you but I dont know how you got that haha